# BigQuery - How can I find the closest row to any other given row within the same table?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table which looks like this:

```
 -----------------------------------
|location|address|latitude|longitude|
 -----------------------------------
|1       |a      |20      |21       |
|1       |b      |21      |22       |
|1       |c      |23      |24       |
|2       |d      |45      |50       |
|2       |e      |46      |47       |
|2       |f      |40      |45       |
 -----------------------------------
```

I am trying to find which row is the closest (distance wise) to any given row of the table (for each location group) and to return this distance as a new column:

Expected output

```
 --------------------------------------------
|location|address|latitude|longitude|distance|
 --------------------------------------------
|1       |a      |20      |21       |1.41    | <- Closest neighbour is b
|1       |b      |21      |22       |1.41    | <- Closest neighbour is a
|1       |c      |23      |24       |2.82    | <- Closest neighbour is b
|2       |d      |45      |50       |1.41    | <- Closest neighbour is e
|2       |e      |46      |51       |1.41    | <- Closest neighbour is d
|2       |f      |41      |46       |2.82    | <- Closest neighbour is d
 --------------------------------------------
```

In the expected output example I've calculated the Euclidean distance but I need the Haversine distance (using ST_DISTANCE in bigquery) it's just that the Euclidean is easier to calculate by hand.

My table is a sample of the actual data and contains ~500k rows. I can do a full outer join with this sample table but the full table has ~30m rows so this approach is not feasible.

Comment: Doesn't the constraint on location group limit the search enough to be fairly efficient?

Comment: see these two posts for ideas
https://mentin.medium.com/nearest-neighbor-in-bigquery-gis-7d50ebd5d63 and 
https://mentin.medium.com/nearest-neighbor-using-bq-scripting-373241f5b2f5